# Adding and subtracting values from columns in dataframe

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr, dplyr

I've a dataframe as under:

```
+-----+---------+-----+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+------------+
| ID  | CURRENT | JAN | FEB | CURRENT_IN_2018 | JAN_2018 | FEB_2018 | UNITS_SWAP |
+-----+---------+-----+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+------------+
| 123 |       2 |   3 |   4 |               5 |        6 |        7 |         12 |
| 456 |       1 |   5 |   0 |               4 |        8 |        6 |          6 |
+-----+---------+-----+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+------------+
```

What I'm trying to do here is subtract the number in `UNITS_SWAP` from `CURRENT_IN_2018`, `JAN_2018` and `FEB_2018` sequentially until the number in UNITS_SWAP reaches zero. Also while doing this, add the number of subtracted `UNITS_SWAP` from each row to their respective matching rows, for instance if 5 units are deducted from current_in_2018 then add 5 units in CURRENT, so on and so forth for JAN and FEB such that the end result is as under:

```
+-----+---------+-----+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+------------+
| ID  | CURRENT | JAN | FEB | CURRENT_IN_2018 | JAN_2018 | FEB_2018 | UNITS_SWAP |
+-----+---------+-----+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+------------+
| 123 |       7 |   9 |   5 |               0 |        0 |        6 |          0 |
| 456 |       5 |   7 |   0 |               0 |        6 |        6 |          0 |
+-----+---------+-----+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+------------+
```

Script to load the data:

```
DF <- data.frame(ID = c(123,456), 
                  CURRENT = c(2,1), 
                  JAN = c(3,5),
                  FEB=c(4,0),                  
                  CURRENT_2018 = c(5,4), 
                  JAN_2018 = c(6,8),
                  FEB_2018=c(7,6),
                  UNITS_SWAP =c(12,6))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this - though note that it will overwrite your source DF:

```
cols <- c('CURRENT', 'JAN', 'FEB')
for (i in 1:NROW(DF)) {
  while (DF[i, 'UNITS_SWAP'] > 0) {
    for (col in cols) {
      excess <- min(DF[i,'UNITS_SWAP'], DF[i, paste0(col, '_2018')])
      DF[i, col] <- DF[i, col] + excess
      DF[i, paste0(col, '_2018')] <- DF[i, paste0(col, '_2018')] - excess
      DF[i, 'UNITS_SWAP'] <- DF[i, 'UNITS_SWAP'] - excess
    }
  }
}
```

Because your columns have a definite structure (`column` matching `column_2018`), we just need to run through them in the order you specified, and paste `_2018` to get the relevant matching column.